# Update bootstrap form from a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I would like to populate a `bootstrap` form with results from a `mongo query` using `handlebars` but am not sure where to put the relevant expressions.

For example, if the code is:

```
 <form method="post" action="/students" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">STUDENT</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname">
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and, say I have the following `{{surname}}` and `{{firstname}}` expressions, is there a place in the code I can put them to ensure that when the page renders the forms contain the surname and firstname objects already? Is this even possible?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you want the inputs value to be filled. You can set the inputs value like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" value="{{$surname}}">
```